# How can I use inotifywait on Raspbian to watch a directory for file changes and upload changed files only using dropbox-uploader.sh?

Tags: linux, filesystems, dropbox, raspbian

How can I use inotifywait on Raspbian to watch a directory for file changes and upload changed files only using dropbox-uploader.sh?

Hello,

Please note I am using dropbox-uploader.sh by Andrea Fabrizi specifically in this example and not the standard Dropbox client.

I have a folder which I want to check recursively for file changes.

Every time a file changes I want to upload that file specifically to Dropbox using dropbox-uploader.sh script by Andrea Fabrizi.

I will probably use the inotifywait tool in this scenario. The -m switch makes it check a directory indefinitely. But I still need write with the rest of the syntax.

Can anyone help me?

Vesa

Update:

I have made some more resarch about inotifywait. I will probably use both -m and -r flags, which should make this script read the directories recursively.

So something like inotifywait -m -r and then [put name of changed file into variable such as $CHANGED_FILE]

Comment: what exactly is the problem ? It seems to me that you have a tool to check whether there where file changes. So you could just run a script that runs the dropbox-uploader.sh in case the inotifywait tool says that there where file changes ?

Comment: The problem is the syntax. I am fairly good at talking to humans at least when it comes to exactly defining a problem and making sure I'm understood. However, computers will not interpret human language directly as you know and I need to get every one of those little semicolons, commas and strings correctly into the little bash script file. It's new year's eve, please help a brother out.

Comment: this question might help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283868/bash-script-detecting-change-in-files-from-a-directory

Comment: Update: 

I have made some more resarch about inotifywait. I will probably use both -m and -r flags, which should make this script read the directories recursively.

So something like inotifywait -m -r and then [put name of changed file into a variable such as $CHANGED_FILE]

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have your plan. Perhaps you just need to install `inotify-tools` (`apt-get install inotify-tools`).